# Loading data from List Box to Picture Box

Tags: c#

:)

I'm having a slight issue where I'm trying to view picture files from my computer on a picture box when I select them. The files appear in the list box but won't appear on the picture box when selected

This is my code

```
using System;                                                                   /    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void getPictures_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] filters = { "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.bmp" };

            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Pictures");

            var files = new List<FileInfo>();

            foreach (var filter in filters)
            {
                var results = directory.GetFiles(filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                files.AddRange(results);
            }

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                lbName.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }
            var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            var result = dialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string path = dialog.SelectedPath;
                lblText.Text = path;
            }
        }

        private void lbName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(((FileInfo)lbName.SelectedItem).FullName);
        }
        private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(((FileInfo)lbName.SelectedItem).FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried a number of ways but this is the current code I'm working with. Anyone see where I'm going wrong? I'm still new to C# and don't know all the syntax off by heart but I'm getting there. Any help would be more than appreciated.

Milly

Comment: Does the lbName_SelectedIndexChanged method get called?

Comment: I definitely see that your code has loading list box and then for some reason showing dialog. And second, you load a file name into listbox but asking for FileInfo

Comment: Looking at your code it appears that you changed the name of your ListBox, you need to make sure that your EventHandlers are still attached to your Control. You can do that by selecting the ListBox, hitting F4 to bring up the Properties Box, clicking on the Lightning Bolt and making sure your SelectedIndexChanged and MouseDoubleClick Events have a handler attached to them.  You code did work for me, I was able to load the pictures into the PictureBox by clicking on your ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

You do add the filename (`lbName.Items.Add(file.Name);`) to the listbox and afterwards cast it back to `(FileInfo)lbName.SelectedItem`. I checked your code with `lbName` being a *listBox* - did not work for me...

I changed your code to this one

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getPictures(); // load pics from hdd
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(((FileInfo)listBox1.SelectedItem).FullName);
    }

    private void getPictures()
    {
        string[] filters = { "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.bmp" };
        // change path to yours
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures");

        var files = new List<FileInfo>();

        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            var results = directory.GetFiles(filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            files.AddRange(results);
        }

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file);
        }
        // not quite sure what this code should do - so I comment out - as I do not think it is necessary for your question!
        //var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        //var result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        //if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        //{
        //    string path = dialog.SelectedPath;
        //    lblText.Text = path;
        //}
    }
```

And now it worked fine for me!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This didn't work for me.

Comment: What did not work for you? I run this code on my machine - worked like a charm. What error do you get? Whats the problem?

Comment: It does the same as my original code, loads the files into the Listbox but then nothing in the picture box when I select a file. I don't get any errors it just doesn't load.

Comment: Right now I also don't see where you load it into Pic box

Comment: @Milly please confirm: have you changed the line `lbName.Items.Add(file.Name);` to `lbName.Items.Add(file);`? That is, add `FileInfo` objects instead of strings to the `ListBox`.

Comment: Actually I think the cast is the problem. While I'd say this answer will work, simpler would be to add strings to the `ListBox` and treat them as strings not `FileInfo` objects. Like this: `Image.FromFile(lbName.SelectedItem.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getPictures();
        }
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(((FileInfo)listBox1.SelectedItem).FullName);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        }

```
    private void getPictures()
    {
        string[] filters = { "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.bmp" };
        string resulPath = ""; // var that will hold the path that returns on the user search
        // not quite sure what this code should do - so I comment out - as I do not think it is necessary for your question!
        var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        var result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = dialog.SelectedPath;
            resulPath = path;
        }

        // Here i set the DirectoryInfo with the var resulPath
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"" + resulPath + "");

        var files = new List<FileInfo>();

        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            var results = directory.GetFiles(filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            files.AddRange(results);
        }

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should explain this a little bit.